# When the size of minimum edge cover is equal to the size of maximum independent set?

Tags: graph-theory, duality-theorems

We know that the size of the minimum edge cover is always equal to or greater than the size of the maximum independent set of the same graph. I want to know is there any special type of graphs that these are always equal?

**Edit:**

One answer is:
**bipartite graphs with no isolated vertex.**

Is there any other types of graphs with this property?